# Excel formula for comparing columns where text IS LIKE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I work as a data analyst in a clinic and we're currently working on determining how many patients saw their assigned provider at their last visit. I typically run the reports and then export them to Excel for easier filtering. Previously, I was using a report that showed all the visit information along with `RenderingProviderID` and `PrimaryCareProviderID`, the former being the provider that actually saw the patient during the visit and the latter being the provider the patient was actually assigned to. It was easy to just add a column containing a formula to just look and see whether the IDs matched and then show a flag if they didn't.

Now I'm using a different table where, instead of provider IDs, the result columns use their names. Better yet, the new Rendering Provider field just displays the last name while the PCP field shows full name and credentials. Results end up looking like this:

```
Visit ID      Rendering Provider      Primary Care Provider
---------------------------------------------------------------
00001         Smith                   Smith, John MD
00002         Smith                   Doe, Jane MD
```

Is there a formula I can use to find partial text matches in those two columns? I know what I want/need to do but I don't know the syntax. I used to just add an extra column containing some form of IF statement and copy the formula all the way down - I'd usually just write it to leave the row blank for any matches and then display some sort of text for cases like the second example above where the RP and PCP didn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CountIf()` with a wildcard:

`=IF(COUNTIF(C2,"*"&B2&"*")>0,"Match!","")`

[image]

You can tweak as necessary. If you just want to show where there's *no* match, just change the `...>0,"","No Match")` part.

Note: This will also match `Rendering` of "Smith" to a `Primary Care Provider` called `Johnsmith Jones`.  If you just need to match the last names, use `B2&"*"` instead of `"*"&B2&"*"`.

Comment: `=IF(FIND(B2,C2)>0,"Match!","")` would be a bit simpler, no?

Comment: @AlexM good call, I tend to forget about `Find()` for some reason.